# 我可不觉得 - agree or disagree?

Tags: meaning

I worked with dialogue of two persons:

A: 外边下雨. 挺有意思.
B: **我可不觉得**. 上个星期我穿了新衣服出门, 忽然倾盆大雨. 我的衣服报废了.

可不 - vocabulary translation gives "1) that's just the way it is. 2) exactly".
But here Person B is complaining about the rain and spoiled clothes. So does Person B agree with A?
Or may be "可不觉得" here is a short form of "可是 不觉得"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same as "I don't think so".

```
我 **可**(means emphasize) 不觉得
我不觉得
不觉得
不
```

When it's a single word "可不", as you post, it is an interjection often used when spoken; it means "exactly" or "you're right".

For example:

```
你真帅
那可不
```

And there won't be any usage of this meaning in the form of `"我" + "可不"`,  especially when they are two characters behind "可不". 
Just remember the usage scenarios of oral language like this (a sentence only has 3 characters).

And why can this negative word be used to represent approval?
This is called 反诘 ("rhetorical question").

Answer (score 3):

In 我可不觉得, you should not take 可不 as a word and instead you should separate it.  The sentence is actually read as 我/可/不觉得.

可 engages the contrast to what A have said. B is trying to convey that he bears the reverse opinion to A about 外面下雨挺有意思, that is, 外面下雨 没有意思.

我可不觉得 can be translated as *I **just** don't feel that way.* **just** adds an emphasis like 可 does. 我不觉得 can be *I don't feel that way*.